# Can't get a div to Center

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what I managed to change but just then one of my div's I was working with would not center, my html is below

```
<div id="footer">
   <p>foo</p>
</div>
```

And my css is here,

```
#footer {
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #EBEBEB;
    color: #3B3738;
    padding: 0.3%;

    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;

    margin: 0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;

    font-weight: 300!important;



}
```

I have tried numerous solutions already offered but they dont seem to get it to center.

After a bit of testing, it appers it is something to do with this Jquery Script, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/ which is adding the following style onto the footer `position: absolute;`

**EDIT:** I solved this by simply adding this to the css, im not really sure why it would work but it did,

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Comment: you can add vertical-align: middle; width:100%;

Comment: In order to center anything in CSS, look at this http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 5):

Use `display:block;` instead of `display:inline-block;`. That will solve it

If using `inline-block` is necessary for your layout then I'd recommend using `flexbox` or `float` instead.

```css
#footer {
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #EBEBEB;
    color: #3B3738;
    padding: 0.3%;

    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;

    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;

    font-weight: 300!important;

}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
   <p>foo</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you just have to give vertical-align which align text vertically and width:100% to full width as same as screen width.

```css
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #EBEBEB;
    color: #3B3738;
    padding: 0.3%;
    vertical-align:middle;

    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;

    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;

    font-weight: 300!important;

}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
   <p>foo</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want a center align element. Use it

```
.center {
margin: auto;
width: 60%;
border: 3px solid #73AD21;
padding: 10px;
}
```